# Did Gordon Ramsay actually go vegan?

Tags: veganism

Last month celebrity chef Gordon Ramsay [posted on Twitter](https://twitter.com/GordonRamsay/status/985948048068145152) that he is going to "give this #vegan thing a try". Is Gordon Ramsay actually going vegan? This would be a huge reversal from his earlier statement that [he will never go vegan](https://twitter.com/GordonRamsay/status/840906140460449792).

[image]

Comment: Downvoters: please consider adding a comment about whether you think this entire category of questions is bad, or just this question in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the only person who can really answer this is Ramsay himself, **I believe he is not going vegan**. The comment was posted [alongside a picture of vegan pizza](https://twitter.com/GordonRamsay/status/985948048068145152) at his then newly opened restaurant. Seems more like a controversy-causing promo of his new place more than anything.

He is still posting pictures of steaks and so on, he never confirmed the above mentioned sentence and, given his history with veganism, if Gordon ever turns vegan, it is because the whole world did an he wants his business to stay afloat. I mean, he said if his kids turned vegetarian, he would *sit them on a fence and electrocute them*. He is a showman who built his entire persona on being offensive, not caring.